# Adjust the height of y axes in scatter plot in Plotly instead of having it fixed

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I wrote the code as follows using Plotly. This is connected to some filter.
The problem is I can have varies number of category (code) on my Y axes.

How can I adjust the height and space between two code which is shown in the attached picture if I choose 2 code it should be small, when I choose 50, it must be bigger. I want it to automatically adjust height based on number of selected code instead of having it fixed.

```
def chart(df):

    
    color_discrete_map = {'df1': 'rgb(255,0,0)',
                      'df2': 'rgb(0,255,0)',
                      'df3': '#11FCE4',
                      'df4': '#9999FF',
                      'df5': '#606060',
                      'df6': '#CC6600'}


    fig = px.scatter(df, x='DATE', y='CODE', color='SOURCE', width=1200,
                     height=800,color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map)

    fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')

    fig.update_layout(
        margin=dict(l=250, r=0, t=0, b=20),

    )
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%y-%m", tickmode = 'linear',  tick0 = 0.5,dtick = 0.75))

    fig.update_xaxes(ticks= "outside",
                     ticklabelmode= "period", 
                     tickcolor= "black", 
                     ticklen=10, 
                     minor=dict(
                         ticklen=4,  
                         dtick=7*24*60*60*1000,  
                         tick0="2016-07-03", 
                         griddash='dot', 
                         gridcolor='white')
                    )
    
    fig.update_layout(yaxis={"dtick":1},margin={"t":0,"b":0},height=500)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you not use something like `myheight = 20*df.segment.nunique()` and assign it to `height` in `px.scatter(...)`?

Comment: Don't use the matplotlib tag for plotly questions. Additionally, this question lacks imports and data, so it's not a complete [mre].

Comment: Thank Redox, it works well

Comment: I used  height= 80 *df.CODE.nunique(), which my plot has nice size when data is small, but the when I have a lot of segment, I dont like the distance, any idea?

Comment: Also I use the slider here which this affect the size of slider as well.

Comment: For height, you can try add a constant like 40 or 50 and then add 20*myHeight and see if that works... you will need to fine tune the numbers and check if it is to your liking. Rgd slider - there is no code here, you will need to create a new question for the same

Comment: Add this constant to where?

Comment: If you dont use @redox, I wont know you mentioned me :-) What I meant was to change myheight creation to something like this `myheight = 40+ 20*df.segment.nunique()`, then test with one segment, then 2, 3... and see if that helps. 40 is the constant